# Flow: Using custom array types in function response

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I'm using Firebase Firestore queries. I've defined a custom object type (`TodoItem`) which I want in the response which I'd expect to be in an array collection (`TodoCollection`).

I'm having issues getting this flow typed though. Below is my code, where by I'm getting the following error within the `onCollectionUpdate` function:

`[flow] function (This type is incompatible with TodoCollection)`

```
type TodoItem = {
  key: ?string,
  title: ?string,
  foo: ?string,
}

type TodoCollection = $ReadOnlyArray<TodoItem>

const onCollectionUpdate: TodoCollection = (querySnapshot: QuerySnapshot) => {
  const collection = []

  querySnapshot.forEach((doc: DocumentSnapshot) => {
    const { title, foo } = doc.data()
    const entry: TodoItem = {
      key: doc.id,
      // doc, // DocumentSnapshot
      title,
      foo,
    }

    collection.push(entry)
  })

  return collection
}
```

The array ideally could be empty which is whats throwing me off a little. Any help / guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: You should use `map()` instead.

Comment: Whether I should use `forEach` or `map` is irrelevant - its just an example. The same Flow warning persists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
const onCollectionUpdate: TodoCollection
```

You just declared a variable of type `TodoCollection`, which is an array.

You're assigning it a function, which is not an array, so you get an error.